# Magento refusing to connect after installation

Tags: magento2, installation

I am using Magento 2 Developer's Guide to learn magento. Following the instructions for setting up the local environment I used Vagrant to install and run magento on a UNIX box. The VagrantFile executes fine and from the execution logs it looks like magento is installed and the server is up.

1)  Here's how we've defined the ip info. in vagrant file :

```
config.vm.network "private_network", ip: vagrantConfig['ip']
```

2)  ip value in the config file :

```
ip: 192.168.10.10
```

3) I then modified the hosts file on my host machine to include this :

```
192.168.10.10   magento.box
```

Here's what I get when I try to access magento installation from the browser :
[image]

Any thoughts on how to get this to work ? I am out of ideas on this.

Comment: Try pinging `magento.box` to make sure it's coming back with the IP you assigned - to rule out any host file problems.

Comment: @AricWatson The ping responds. I did "ping magento.box" and it responded with : Reply from 192.168.10.10: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.10.10: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.10.10: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.10.10: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64

Ping statistics for 192.168.10.10:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 1ms, Average = 0ms . So the ping works ok. Any other thing I should check for ?

Answer (score -1):

Update : I did a2enmod rewrite and restarted the server and it works now.